# How to print "zero width non-joiner" using perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, bash, text

I've searched about this problem, but all the discussions were around how to remove "zero width non-joiner" character from a string or replace it with the standard space. So, I know how to detect and remove it in a given string.
Now my question is how to print this string in perl? I know how to do it in Python and ruby, but it doesn't work in perl.
In ruby I used to do it simply by:

```
mystring.gsub!(/\s+/,'<200c>')
```

And it works fine. But following the same way in Perl, it doesn't work. Actually I have tried the following, but it doesn't return the proper output:

```
$mystring =~ s/\s+/\x{200C}/g;
```

The point is that I can detect this character in Perl, but I can not print it. Any Ideas about this problem?

Comment: what output you want, and what output you get

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html. I tried `use open ':encoding(utf8)'` and it seemed to work.

Comment: I enter some text like: ab{space}cd and I want it to be like: ab{non-joiner space}cd. But I don't get non-joiner space in between. Instead of it, I get double spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write properly a string containing a utf8 sequence you should use `binmode()` on that stream. What I suggest you try is `binmode( STDOUT, ':utf8' );` and then print the string. The `length( $mystring )` function can help you tell if the string contains more characters than the visible ones and verify a successful substitution.

Comment: I don't get the correct length, even for the original text. May be the reason is that my string is in Persian characters, not in English.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I want to replace the space with some other character (say X) it works perfectly. and I don't have any problem with it. the problem is with the non-joiner space.

Comment: Currently I'm using (use encoding "utf8";) and (open STDOUT, "<:encoding(UTF-8)" ;) to tell the interpreter that I am using UTF-8 characters and I want to open an utf-8 STDOUT stream. But I also tried (binmode( STDOUT, ':utf8' );) and it was the same. nothing changed in the output.

Comment: Can you supply a sample string and the version number of your perl distribution?

Comment: My perl version is: v5.10.1